# Android rom and kernel build error

Tags: kernel, android, compiling

I am trying android building but I have error I cant solve it. help please I am using ubuntu 15.04  [compile error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12845359/)

Comment: are you using andriod studio? what language are you trying to compile? can you give us more details? Ca you show us the code, you are trying to compile?

Comment: I don't use android studio and my pc language Turkish. I am trying compile cm10.2 for samsung gts8530. Before I built cm10.2 successfuly on ubuntu 14.04 but now it gives error